# Dealing with mobile numbers - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008. I am trying to get values in Column A based on the mobile numbers in Column B. The mobile numbers can be in different formats like this:

```
 1. 44 752 111 1234
 2. 07521111234
 3. 07521111234
 4. 447521111234
 5. 7521111234
 6. 752 111 1234 etc...etc.
```

I need the syntax for extracting data in column A based on the mobile number, but only with the 10 digits starting from 75 as the search criteria. The prefixes (44,0) and the spaces in between must be disregarded.

Also note that  in the 10 digits I am referring to the numbers start with all combinations, I think only 7 remains constant. i.e it can be 077 or 075 or 078 or 75 or 78 and so on..

Can you please help ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CHARINDEX` to help you solve your problem,

```
SELECT  ColA, 
        SUBSTRING(ColA, CHARINDEX('75', ColA), LEN(ColA) - CHARINDEX('75', ColA) + 1)
FROM    TableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f15b9/4)
- [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

OR

```
SELECT  ColA, 
        RIGHT(ColA, LEN(ColA) - CHARINDEX('75', ColA) + 1) ColB
FROM    TableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f15b9/8)

OUTPUT of BOTH query,

```
╔═════════════════╦══════════════╗
║      COLA       ║     COLB     ║
╠═════════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 44 752 111 1234 ║ 752 111 1234 ║
║ 07521111234     ║ 7521111234   ║
║ 07521111234     ║ 7521111234   ║
║ 447521111234    ║ 7521111234   ║
║ 7521111234      ║ 7521111234   ║
║ 752 111 1234    ║ 752 111 1234 ║
╚═════════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Comment: Hi JW, thanks for your reply. This helps to a certain extent. What if the 10 digits I am referring to the numbers start with different combinations and just 7 remaining constant. i.e it can be 077 or 075 or 078 or 75 or 78 or 73 or 79 and so on..

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Tels AS TABLE (no varchar(20))

INSERT INTO @Tels
VALUES
('44 752 111 1234'),
('07521111234'),
('07521111234'),
('447521111234'),
('7521111234'),
('752 111 1234')

SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(no, ' ', ''), 3, 10) from @Tels where no like '75%'
```

regarding your second question...

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(no, ' ', ''), 3, 10) from @Tels where no like '7[0-9]%'
UNION
SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(no, ' ', ''), 4, 10) from @Tels where no like '07[0-9]%'
```

Comment: Hi Yaugen, thanks for your reply. This helps to a certain extent. What if the 10 digits I am referring to the numbers start with different combinations and just 7 remaining constant. i.e it can be 077 or 075 or 078 or 75 or 78 or 73 or 79 and so on..

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with fixed length no's (eg UK mobile numbers) I've found the best approach to be:

```
RIGHT(REPLACE([MyColumn],' ',''),10)
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f15b9/15/0)